# Why do I need to include EOF in my loop condition?

Tags: c, while-loop, eof, getchar

I have been given a task to write a program that will take keyboard input (excluding space) and print to a .txt file without using an array.

I tried to use a while loop to do this but was getting an infinite loop, I then came on to stack overflow and found a solution within a different problem, EUREKA!

Adding:

```
&& ch != EOF
```

solved my problem.

However, I do not fully understand why the solution works and would like help to understand why this second condition was needed.

```
while((ch=getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
   {
       putc(ch, fin);
   }
   fclose(fin);
   return 0;
```

Thank you.

Comment: If `getchar` hits end-of-file it will never return a `'\n'`. So you need one other reason to exit the loop.

Comment: So is getchar a file that contains the user input?

Comment: No, `getchar()` is a function that reads from standard input.

Comment: My confusion was not understanding where 'getchar()' was reading from, this helped my understanding. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the return value of `getchar` is the character read on success, and
`EOF` on error or when the end-of-file has been reached:

> *man getchar*
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> `fgetc()`, `getc()` and `getchar()` return the character read as an `unsigned char` cast to an `int` or **`EOF` on end of file or error.**

There are several reasons as to why `stdin` might reach end-of-file:

- The user pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (on Unix/Linux) which causes
  `stdin` to close
- `stdin` was connected to a pipe (`$ cat file.txt | ./myprogram`) and the pipe
  closed because `cat` ended.
- `stdin` was connected to a redirection (`$ ./myprogram < file.txt`) and it
  reached the end of `file.txt`

On all this cases, `getchar` will eventually return `EOF` and you cannot keep
reading. If you do

```
while((ch=getchar()) != '\n')
{
    ...
}
```

and `stdin` closes, then you end up in an endless loop, als `EOF != '\n'` always
evaluates to true. So in order to protect yourself from that, you have to check
if the read operation failed. And you do that by checking whether the reading
function returned `EOF`. That's why

```
int ch;
while((ch=getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
{
    ...
}
```

is the correct way of looping with `getchar`. Also note that `ch` must be of
type `int`.

Note also that this applies for **all** `FILE` buffers (opened in read mode),
not only to `stdin`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain, this has made things much clearer.

Comment: @8TrackRobot The man page for getchar explains all of this.  It should be a first line of reference when understanding a problem while coding in C.